# css postioning a box in between of its parent

Tags: css

This is my code snippet :

**Html**

```
<div class="app-cont">
    <div class="app-head">
        Additional Comments :
    </div>
    <div class="app-main">
        balallalalalallalalalala
        <br/>
        jaslnflkasnlsnlksanlknslnwkin
        <br />
        lknlkanfklnlk
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```css
div {
    color:white;
}
.app-cont {
    background: black;
    width: 90%;
    padding-top: 2.5px;
    padding-bottom: 2.5px;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    border-radius: 5px;
}
.app-head {
    background: #484848;
    width: 25%;
    margin-bottom: auto;
    display: inline-block;
    border-top-right-radius:2px;
    -moz-border-top-right-radius:2px;
    border-bottom-right-radius:2px;
    -moz-border-bottom-right-radius:2px;
}
.app-main {
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: justify;
}
```

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/kritya/Ues8Q/)

It works till i dont add enough content on the div with class `app-main`. But when i add enough content in the div the div with class `app-head` gets to the bottom.

While i want it in the middle.
How can i do this ?

Comment: What is it exactly that you want to do? Do you have a screenshot or diagram of your desired outcome?

Comment: Have a look at this article which explains css positioning really well and has helped me on numerous occaisions. Basically you make the parent div, in your case .app-cont position: relative and any child divs as position: absolute and give them specific dimensions to control your layout exactly.
[css positioning](http://www.barelyfitz.com/screencast/html-training/css/positioning/)

Comment: @Kyle Sevenoaks - I think he described his problem pretty clear :)

Comment: @kyle The div with text `Additional Comments :` should be placed in the middle of its parent

Comment: Aha, well.. Early morning blurry eyes :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add vertical align style.

```css
.app-head,.app-main{
    vertical-align:middle;
}
```

You can use it on `inline-block` elements to position near other `inline-block` elements or near `inline` elements.

Comment: It works. You must make a style on both elements as I described in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Well I wasn't sure entirely what the goal was, but if I understood you correctly, you wanted to keep the block holding the additional comments text in the middle of the text to the right?

I've updated your fiddle to see if I've got the solution you need: [Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Ues8Q/1/)

I've positioned .app-head absolutely, and used a top:50% and a negative margin to keep it centred vertically. You also have to give .app-cont a relative position for this to work, and the comments section needs a left-margin slightly greater than the width of .app-head.

Anyway, hope that helps!

Comment: It is an outdated, overweight and messy solution. It should be forgotten in a day when we all forgot that IE6 was a web browser...

Answer (score 0):

I did some other changes as well..

http://jsfiddle.net/Ues8Q/4/

..but the main idea is this:

Outer container has: `position: relative;`

The thing you want to center has: `position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 50%; margin: -exactly half of the height of this element; height: whatever it is;`

and requirement is that the element you want to center has fixed height...

Comment: The same as Dave's solution - it was good when we cared about IE6. It should be burried now.

Comment: @avall Dan Dan Dan Danan ananana http://www.ie6countdown.com/ ..and I dont mean to sound rude but.. who are you to say "when we cared about ie6" as you are not the OP..

Comment: Of course you can make webpages on tables or using as much absolute positioning as you like but if you want to make something cool and lightweight, consider to forget about it already. I don't care about these statistics anymore because we must go on. Not to stay in one place, right? Good luck in your IE6.

Comment: Oh, and, I don't want to sound rude but that is called evolution.

Comment: @avall of course i dont use tables.. but absolute positioning is not just for ie6 you know. It can be used in many different cases and no, I dont support ie6 myself.. but many companies and people still see that ie6 has to be supported.

Comment: So, if you don't support it and OP doesn't support it, why are you arguing? :). Your solution doesn't fit in here. He doesn't have fixed height. Bear with it silently.

Comment: @avall I dont think that OP said that ie6+ support is not needed.. I totally missed that if he did. But, when it isnt stated I always asume that it is needed. Even if you or the OP actually dont need ie6 support it is still a valid answer. Youre making a big number out of not supporting ie6 yourself.. In my books more support is always better than less support.. few extra silly lines of css isnt going to matter.

Comment: Few extra silly lines? :D. Okay, whatever. He uses inline-block which isn't valid with ie6. End of topic. Bye.

Comment: @avall I dont see what the problem in here is? Youre getting all worked up because I want to offer support for ie6. This I would understand if OP wanted ie6 support and I would refuse to tell solution for that because ie6 is old browser. But, in this case i just see it as extra goodness. I dont understand your reasoning. It's like Position: absolute; did something to offend you and you want to punish it.. thats how it seems like.

Comment: @Lollero let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/2981/discussion-between-avall-and-lollero)